# Web service vs. Office Automation

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, office-automation

I have ASP.NET Web Service, that works under IIS.
I use Microsoft.Interop DLL to convert file from XML Table format to Excel 2003.
In my code I have reference to Microsoft.Interop DLL version 12. When I try to use this web service from VS, everything working correct.

But when I move my web service to 64-bit Windows Server 2008 I have problem with this convertion.

I place my Microsoft.Interop DLL into bin folder of my web service.
I also tried to make build for 86x and 64x platforms, but nothing changed.

Without converting my web service working correct.

What may cause this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net web service using office 2010 COM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382704/asp-net-web-service-using-office-2010-com)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Office Automation in a server process like a web service. It's designed to automate the Office *desktop* applications. In a service, it doesn't work, or causes bugs that are difficult to reproduce, is unsupported, and may even be a violation of your license with Microsoft.