# Using Microsoft Interop to read and write into excel cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop, office-automation

I have a excel file on web server where my website deployed. The scenario, I have a screen which allow user to download an Excel file from web server and save to local drive then select the same file path to export the data, but I'm getting the below error.

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user. To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file
>   in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click
>   "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET
>   account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

This is my code:

```
private void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
    object missingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    decimal wkOpenBal = 0.00m;
    decimal wkAddition = 0.00m; 
    decimal wkDisposal = 0.00m;
    string rptDt = "";

    decimal os_p = 0.00M;
    decimal os_s = 0.00M;
    decimal closs_16_25 = 0.00M;
    decimal closs_26 = 0.00M;
    decimal os_clr_p = 0.00M;
    decimal os_whs_p = 0.00M;
    decimal os_clr_s = 0.00M;
    decimal os_whs_s = 0.00M;           
    decimal mark_to_mkt = 0.00M;
    decimal mark_to_mkt_error = 0.00M;


    if(txtWeeklyFile.Value != "")
    {
        //DATABASE CALL
        objBursaSubmission = (IBursaSubmission) ObjectFactory.Instance.GetObject(ObjectIdentifier.BursaSubmissionManager);                      
        dsResult = objBursaSubmission.GetReportData(txtRptdt.Text);

        try
        {
            if(dsResult != null && dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if(System.IO.File.Exists(txtWeeklyFile.Value.ToString()))
                {
                    wkOpenBal = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WK_OPENBAL"]);
                    wkAddition = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WK_ADDITION"]);
                    wkDisposal = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WK_DISPOSAL"]);
                    rptDt = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LOGICAL_DT"].ToString();                

                    os_p = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OS_P"]);
                    os_s = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OS_S"]);
                    closs_16_25 = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CLOSS_16_25"]);
                    closs_26 = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CLOSS_26"]);
                    os_clr_p = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OS_CLR_P"]);
                    os_whs_p = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OS_WHS_P"]);
                    os_clr_s = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OS_CLR_S"]);
                    os_whs_s = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OS_WHS_S"]);
                    mark_to_mkt = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MARK_TO_MKT"]);
                    mark_to_mkt_error = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["mark_to_mkt_error"]);

                    decimal clr_total_p = os_clr_p + os_whs_p;
                    decimal clr_total_s = os_clr_s + os_whs_s;

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(txtWeeklyFile.Value.ToString(),Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);

                    //SHEET MARKET POSITION SHEET 1                                                             
                    Worksheet sheetMarktetPosition1 = (Worksheet)wBook.Sheets[1];                       
                    Range mPositionRange = sheetMarktetPosition1.UsedRange;                 

                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[6,7]).Value2 = rptDt.ToString();

                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[14,3]).Value2 = os_p.ToString();
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[14,7]).Value2 = mark_to_mkt.ToString();                         
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[16,3]).Value2 = os_s.ToString();                            
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[15,5]).Value2 = "";
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[40,3]).Value2 = clr_total_p.ToString();
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)mPositionRange.Cells[41,3]).Value2 = clr_total_s.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //code for any other type of exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot safely use Office Automation from a server process. See the answer to [Editing an Excel document with Macros in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493163/76337) to learn how far you have to go to make this safe. See [ASP.NET Web Service using office 2010 COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382704/asp-net-web-service-using-office-2010-com) to learn what can happen if you just try calling it from ASP.NET.

The problem, briefly, is that Office Automation was designed for the automation, from a desktop application, of the Microsoft Office products, which are desktop applications. All sorts of things don't work properly when you're using them from a server application.

Comment: U r right John, Earlier it was client side with the help of ActiveX control, but again our client disabled ActiveX Control on all user terminal. so we decided to moved to server side.

now we have to keep it to server side and provide the permission too. and its a intranet application there are 4 user who gng to use this application and they are not ready to enable the activex control on IE

any idea how can i make the current server side code up and running?
thanks

Comment: It is not possible to "get it up and running". The very idea of using Office Automation server-side is fundamentally broken. The only exception would be if you follow the pattern of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9493163/76337. Note there's a good reason why his code is so complicated - it's a really bad thing to "fool Mother Nature" by using Office Automation in a manner other than the manner it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have remote desktop access to this server?

You will need to set the permissions on the folder that the Excel file is being exported to as well as setup the permissions in DCOMCNFG so that the AppPool user can automate Excel. (Start, Run, DCOMCNFG, Component Services, Computers, DCOM Config and right click the Microsoft Excel object.

Have you considered an Excel writer instead? Such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thanks Makit
no i dont have remote desktop access. as my client dose not provide server access to vendor employee.

and as far as permission concern, there are multiple user who going to use same screen. now the problem is my code is server side and file at client machine which i have posted in my post. How can i set permission policy at server so when ever user export data to excel file my application dosent throw any error?

any help
thanks

Comment: Good response from a troubleshooting point of view. +1, even if the resultant workaround is not favourable.